# No. of states for HMM acoustic models in Speech Recognition

Tags: speech-recognition, hidden-markov-models, states

Is it necessary that hmm model for each word has same no. of states in speech recognition?

Answer (score 1):

No, in HTK you can choose arbitrary number of states for every model. In Kaldi you usually have 3 states in non-silence phones, 5 states in silence phones. In CMUSphinx each phone has the same number of states for simplicity.